# user defined apex class

Tags: apex, class, wrapper-class

I need to build a wrapper that could essentially hold this format.

```
  {
    
    record: {
     id: 123
     name: abc
     start: 1-jan
     end: 31-jan
     status: completed
     records: [{
                 same format as record above
               },
               {
                 same format as record above
               }]

      }
   }
```

I basically need a tree like structure. how can I do that in a wrapper class?

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? [edit] your question to include that information.

Comment: You should know that such nesting would preclude JSON serialization/deserialization.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Not at all. You can nest indefinitely using a recursive definition.

Comment: @sfdcfox Isn't JSON deserialization limited to 50 levels? maybe I'm thinking of XML.

Comment: Thanks all for your prompt replies, really appreciate it. this JSON structure has about 4 levels. I wanted to know what would be the best way to build a wrapper for something like this.

Comment: @DerekF I just tested this with 100+ nested levels, and it deserialized okay. The practical limits will be somewhere between heap limits and CPU limits.

Comment: @DerekF Actually, tested it with over 1800+ nested elements. I had no idea this would even work, but there we have it. I stopped there because my IDE was starting to freak out trying to highlight balanced braces.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would look like this:

```
public class RecordClass {
    Integer id;
    String name;
    Date start;
    Date end;
    String status;
    Record[] records;
}
public class Record {
    RecordClass record;
}
```

Unfortunately, `end` is a reserved keyword. If you can change the properties to something like `startDate` and `endDate`, then these two classes would work.

Otherwise, you'll have to deal with simply using JSON.deserializeUntyped instead. This is still pretty straight-forward, but involves a bit of casting to get to the correct data types.

For serialization, you can also just use a `Map<String, Object>` data type, which would allow you to nest the records exactly as you specify.